# GCC with Cygwin/Win7: missing syscall.h

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to compile a linux c++ source code on Windows 7 Cygwin and getting following error:

```
$ make
getconf: Unrecognized variable `LFS_CFLAGS'
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -DVERSION='"v1.1.0"'  -c src/main.c -o src/main.o
src/main.c:10:25: schwerwiegender Fehler: sys/syscall.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/syscall.h>
                         ^
Kompilierung beendet.
Makefile:48: recipe for target 'src/main.o' failed
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

I googled this but hadn't any success. Any ideas?

Comment: What Linux system calls do you expect to be able to make on a Windows system? See the "Cygwin is not" section on http://cygwin.com/

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/pyropeter/otrtool/blob/master/src/main.c
I dont actually know what syscall is it trying to invoke. I removed syscall.h from the source code after that it compiled without errors. But the executable doesn't produce file-output, so I suppose that this syscall is somewhere in void decryptFile()

Comment: Found it on line 1016:
  syscall(__NR_ioprio_set, 1, getpid(), 7 | 3 << 13)
Seems to be some debugging stuff not related to the main program....
Still have the question why it doesn't output a file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`syscall.h` is OS specific so syscall specific stuff is likely to fail anyway under cygwin so it's not supported.

You will have to wrap that include under some `#ifdef` and write appropriate porting code for it to run under Windows.

Comment: or Cygwin could have the wrappers for these functions