# Syscall library in windows

Tags: c++, c, system-calls

Is it possible to translate the following functions in `syscall` into something in `windows.h`? If so, someone with information can help me, I can't find anything on google.

```
static inline int __setns(int fd, int nstype) {
    return syscall(__NR_setns, fd, nstype);

}

static inline int __unshare(int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_unshare, flags);
}

static inline int __accept4(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen, int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_accept4, sockfd, addr, addrlen, flags);
}

static inline int __dup3(int oldfd, int newfd, int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_dup3, oldfd, newfd, flags);
}

static inline ssize_t __readlinkat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, char *buf, size_t bufsiz) {
    return syscall(__NR_readlinkat, dirfd, pathname, buf, bufsiz);
}

static inline int __symlinkat(const char *target, int newdirfd, const char *linkpath) {
    return syscall(__NR_symlinkat, target, newdirfd, linkpath);
}

static inline int __linkat(int olddirfd, const char *oldpath,
        int newdirfd, const char *newpath, int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_linkat, olddirfd, oldpath, newdirfd, newpath, flags);
}

static inline int __inotify_init1(int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_inotify_init1, flags);
}

static inline int __faccessat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int mode, int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_faccessat, dirfd, pathname, mode, flags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Those are Linux specific system calls, and there is no direct "translation" on other operating systems.

The only thing you can do under Windows is to try and *emulate* those system calls, but that can only go so far and you will not be able to emulate all of them. A great example of this is Cygwin, which emulates a lot of standard Linux syscalls on windows, providing the [the `unistd.h` header](https://github.com/msys2/Cygwin/blob/master/newlib/libc/sys/linux/sys/unistd.h) just like in any Linux system.

If you want to translate something outside the `unistd.h` header provided by Cygwin I'd say that's not possible unfortunately. You could try writing similar wrappers, but you're not going to really get the same syscall.

Comment: Is there no equivalent call? from windows?

Comment: @IonutAlexandru Nope, there is no equivalent call. As I said, you can only emulate those using Cygwin for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19894482/gcc-with-cygwin-win7-missing-syscall-h it is not possible :(

Comment: @IonutAlexandru oh sorry I did not notice that you were specifically trying to use syscalls outside of the ones defined in `uinstd.h`. Yeah, that's not possible unfortunately.